# Trying to include WebdriverIO into Angular Electron App

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, webdriver-io

**Background:** I'm currently trying to implement the basic [WebdriverIO example](http://webdriver.io/guide.html#Taking-the-first-step) from inside an Angular Electron App. My App is based on the [Angular Electron Boilerplate](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron). I have installed [webdriverio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriverio) and [@types/webdriverio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webdriverio) via npm. Then I created the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { remote, Options } from 'webdriverio';

@Injectable()
export class WebdriverioService {
    remote: typeof remote;
    options: Options;

    constructor() {
        this.options = {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            }
        }
    }

    test(): void {
        remote(this.options) // <-- this line causes the error
            .init()
            .url('http://www.google.com')
            .getTitle().then(function (title) {
                console.log('Title was: ' + title);
            })
            .end()
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}
```

I have marked the critical line with a **comment**. Firstly I get the following compiler warnings:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/launcher.js
138:39-55 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/ConfigParser.js
144:58-75 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/helpers/getImplementedCommands.js
59:44-90 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/launcher.js
812:34-50 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Secondly my App throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT, protocol not found in <<Path to App>>\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar
at notFoundError (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:114)
at Object.fs.readdirSync (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:588)
at getImplementedCommands (getImplementedCommands.js:40)
at Object../node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js (index.js:59)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
at Object../src/app/providers/webdriverio.service.ts (electron.service.ts:10)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:11)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
at Object../src/main.ts (environment.ts:4)
```

I think this issue seems to be mostly **typescript** configuration related, but I'm not shure. I don't really know where to look at. Could someone maybe tell me what I forgot?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specific answer to this, but I am working on [a similar idea](https://github.com/klamping/chester-desktop).

I haven't figured out how to resolve the "the request of a dependency is an expression" issue, but I do know that it doesn't seem to be interfering right now. You could probably ignore that issue.

Electron with asar has been a bit confusing for me as well. Maybe having a look through the repo code I linked above will help out. I know that it has helped me a ton to look through various electron repos out there.